# How to pick the TextInput onChange event type

Tags: typescript, react-native

The case code as below.

```
import { TextInput } from 'react-native'
import { reduxAction } from './reduxActionPath'

interface AppProps {
  reduxAction: typeof reduxAction
}

class CaseComponent extends React.Component<AppProps> {
  // how to define the event type
  handleChange = (str: string) => (e: whatTheTypeOfE) => {
    this.props.reduxAction({ [str]: e.target.value })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <TextInput onChange={this.handleChange('userName')} />
      <TextInput onChange={this.handleChange('password')} />
    )
  }
}
```

It should safely check out the type of e, how to pick of it?

UPDATE:
Now I use the onChangeText to work around of it, but I really want to know how to enable the type of it?

```
import { TextInput } from 'react-native'
import { reduxAction } from './reduxActionPath'

interface AppProps {
  reduxAction: typeof reduxAction
}
interface AppState {
  userName: string
  userPwd: string
}

class CaseComponent extends React.Component<AppProps, AppState> {
  render(){
    return(
      <TextInput onChangeText={(userName) => this.setState({ userName })} />
      <TextInput onChangeText={(userPwd) => this.setState({ userPwd })} />
    )
  }
}
```